# How to find the basis of the kernel of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Say given the function:
$$ T: \mathbb R_{2}[t] \rightarrow \mathbb R_{1}[t]$$
$$ at^{2} + bt + c \rightarrow at + 2c - b $$

We were tasked to find the basis for the kernel of $T$ and $T(\mathbb R_2[t])$.

Where do I start? Could somebody point me in the right direction? I was told to do these steps:
[image]

But I don't even understand the first part. Could somebody explain how the matrix A is generated from writing the polynomials as column vectors? What is the map of T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see. You have to understand that $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$ is a vector space. A basis you could choose is $\{t^2, t, 1\}$ (it is easy to check that really it is). Analogously for $\mathbb{R}_1[t]$, a basis is  $\{t, 1\}$.
Now, in order to obtain the matrix of the transformation $T$, you only have to check that the first vector of the first basis ($t^2=1\cdot t^2+0t+0$) get transformed to $1.t+0$, so the first column of the matrix will be $(1,0)$ (as a column!). And so on for the others two element of the basis to create the other columns.

Comment: Woah, thanks for this! I understand it now. I have an additional question. What exactly is the map of T? And what does it imply in this problem? And how is it related to the image of T?

Comment: About the map of $T$, I am not sure what do you mean... Could you be more specific? And respect to the image of $T$, yo know it is generated by $T(t^2)$, $T(t)$ and $T(1)$. So you must write them down and throw out that dependent vector (or vectors), then you will have a basis for $T(R_2[t])$.

Comment: What does throwing out the 'dependent vector' mean? And what are these dependent vectors? I apologize for the many questions and thanks!

Comment: Well, you have three vectors and you know that the dimension of $T(R_2(t))$ is, at most, 2 (because it is a subspace of $R_1(t)$). So at least one of the three vectors must be leaved out. You have the image is generated by $\{t,-1, 2\}$, and is easy to see that -1 and 2 are linearly dependent vectors (so you can remove the "2", for example) and $t$ and $-1$ are independent, so they remain with us. So $T(R_2(t))$ is the whole $R_1(t)$ (and therefore the kernel must be the vector space 0)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion just notes that the term $at^2+bt+c $ can be identified with the triple $(a,b,c)$ (that is, the term has the coordinates $(c,b,a)$ with the basis $1,t,t^2$).

I think is is easier to compute directly.

Note that $at^2+bt+c = 0$ **iff** $a=b=c=0$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\ker T &=& \{ at^2+bt+c | T(at^2+bt+c) = 0 \} \\
&=& \{ at^2+bt+c | at+2c-b = 0 \} \\
&=& \{ at^2+bt+c | a = 0, b=2c \} \\
&=&  \{ 2 ct +c | c \in \mathbb{R} \} \\
&=& \{ c (2t+1) | c \in \mathbb{R} \} 
\end{eqnarray}
From this we see that $2t+1$ is a basis for $\ker T$.

The image is computed similarly.
\begin{eqnarray}
{\cal R} T &=& \{ T(at^2+bt+c) | at^2+bt+c \in \mathbb{R}_2[t]\} \\
&=& \{ at+2c-b | at^2+bt+c \in \mathbb{R}_2[t]\} \\
&=& \{ at+2c-b | a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
&=& \{ at+d | a,d \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
\end{eqnarray}
And so we see that $t, 1$ form a basis for ${\cal R}T$.

Comment: Where did 't,1' came from?

Comment: The range consists of all terms of the form $at+d = a(t)+d(1)$ where $a,d$ are any real numbers. So the terms $1,t$ are sufficient to represent every element of the range and they are linearly independent, hence they form a basis for the range.